# Magento 2.2 : Cannot Add Subcategory

Tags: database, category, magento2.2

I can't add subcategory in "Catalog > Categories", I get the following error message :

> Something went wrong while saving the category.

In `var/log/debug.log`, I have this :

> [2017-11-13 04:34:03] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1787 When @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY = 1, the statements CREATE
>   TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can be executed in a
>   non-transactional context only, and require that AUTOCOMMIT = 1.,
>   query was: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
>   `tmp_select_fc67d54614b698ebb1a8d4d6da400330` (PRIMARY
>   KEY(`url_rewrite_id`),INDEX `HASHKEY_ENTITY_STORE` USING
>   HASH(`hash_key`),INDEX `ENTITY_STORE` USING
>   HASH(`entity_id`,`store_id`)) ENGINE=`INNODB` IGNORE (SELECT `e`.*,
>   CONCAT(e.store_id,'_', e.entity_id) AS `hash_key` FROM `url_rewrite`
>   AS `e` WHERE (entity_type = 'category') AND (entity_id IN('13')))
>   {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 0):
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1787 When
>   @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY = 1, the statements CREATE TEMPORARY
>   TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can be executed in a non-transactional
>   context only, and require that AUTOCOMMIT = 1., query was: CREATE
>   TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_select_fc67d54614b698ebb1a8d4d6da400330` (PRIMARY
>   KEY(`url_rewrite_id`),INDEX `HASHKEY_ENTITY_STORE` USING
>   HASH(`hash_key`),INDEX `ENTITY_STORE` USING
>   HASH(`entity_id`,`store_id`)) ENGINE=`INNODB` IGNORE (SELECT `e`.*,
>   CONCAT(e.store_id,'_', e.entity_id) AS `hash_key` FROM `url_rewrite`
>   AS `e` WHERE (entity_type = 'category') AND (entity_id IN('13'))) at
>   /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235,
>   PDOException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1787 When
>   @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY = 1, the statements CREATE TEMPORARY
>   TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can be executed in a non-transactional
>   context only, and require that AUTOCOMMIT = 1. at
>   /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"}
>   []

My database is on an Aliyun RDS server, I have no access to GTID parameters.

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this issue by installing this module:
https://github.com/bangerkuwranger/Magento-2-GTID-Safe-URL-Rewrite-Tables

But it only fixed this issue partly.

More information about this bug is available here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11055#issuecomment-344879526